# How to find valid values for fields in the REST API

Tags: api, rest-api, documentation

I have been searching for **documentation** regarding the **REST API**.

All I have found is the Swagger page. It gives a good overview but it doesn't provide any information about valid values for individual fields.
From what I have found there is no such documentation available.

How can I find out what values are valid for all different fields in the API?

Example:
For a POST to `/V1/coupons` (`salesRuleCouponRepositoryV1`), how do I find out what the valid values for **"type"** are and what they mean?

Comment: hello! did you find any response to this? thanks

Comment: Nearly 2 years later and the documentation still doesn't have any answers

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from here

[REST APIs](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html)

You can check **salesRuleCouponRepositoryV1** all actions and valid values from here.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen the Swagger page as I wrote in my question. But what I can't find is the valid values for each field. If i look at "POST salesRuleCouponRepositoryV1" it says that the field "type" is a numeric field. But how do I know what values are valid? Is it 1, 67 or 39774? And what do each number mean?

Comment: Have you study post example from given example?

Comment: Yes, I have. I can't find any information about each individual field, more than the data type.